# How to process Key.Enter and prevent row change on WinForms CustomDataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to stop the enter key on winforms `dataGridView` of changing the row when `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` cell is in `edit-mode` and enter is pressed. Otherwise the functionality should stay normal.

My preferred approach is to create `CustomDataGridView` and override the necessary methods. My approach seem to end `edit-mode` but without firing `CellValidating` event.

Currently this event is used to validate the user input.

```
  public class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView
  {
    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
      if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
      {
        if (MyProcessDialogKey(keyData)) return true;
      }

      return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }

    protected bool MyProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {

      EndEdit();
      return true;
    }
  }
```

How can I raise the `CellValidating` event? Or should I consider different approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the KeyDown Event on the DataGridView like following:

```
private void MyDGV_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
 if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
  {
    //First process your stuff

    //To stop Keypress from doing anything more:
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

More Infos: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx)

Notice: there are many Events where you can end processing with e.Handled = true

Have a nice day

Comment: Good idea. However, I would like to know how to do this by altering the behavior of the DataGridView itself.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to override the OnKeyDown event as such:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyData & Keys.KeyCode) == Keys.Enter)
        return;
    else
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```